# Build fails when installing python on MBA with Mountain Lion using Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I get the following error message and I cannot find the solution in the links that are given.

```
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3
ln -sf pythonw2 "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw"
lipo -extract i386 -output /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32 pythonw
lipo: input file (pythonw) must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified
make[1]: *** [install_pythonw] Error 1
make: *** [frameworkinstallapps] Error 2

Error: python did not build
Logs: /Users/einar/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python/
Help: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
      https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12918
      https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/15199
```

I am trying to follow [this guide](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't RTFM properly.

"Try using the old environment, e.g. brew install --env=std graphviz" from https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting fixed it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
    $ brew install python --framework --with-brewed-openssl
```